# Tkinter Canvas.create_oval does not update color

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to change the color of the line Im drawing on the canvas, with the function change_red. After clicking the buttons which runs the function the value from self.color changes to red, however the line still draws in black.

I've tried to change self.color in the init methode, but it still draws only in black.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter as tk

class Window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.color = "black"
        menubar = tk.Menu(self)
        self.config(menu=menubar)
        operation_menu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        config_menu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Change Color", menu=operation_menu)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=config_menu)
        config_menu.add_command(label="Exit", command=lambda: exit())
        operation_menu.add_command(label="Red", command=lambda: self.change_red())
        self.im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Test.png"))
        self.geometry("500x500")
        self.title("Image Editor")
        self.resizable(False, False)
        self.im_cv = tk.Canvas(width=300, height=200)
        self.im_cv.pack(expand="yes", fill="both")
        self.im_cv.create_image(50, 10, image=self.im, anchor="nw")
        self.im_cv.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.paint)

    def change_red(self):
        self.color = "red"

    def paint(self, event):
        print(self.color)
        x1, y1 = (event.x - 1), (event.y - 1)
        x2, y2 = (event.x + 1), (event.y + 1)
        self.my_canvas = self.im_cv.create_oval(x1, y1,x2,y2, fill=self.color, width=5)

window = Window()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hello stovfl, thanks for your answer. No self.my_canvas is not undefined. I created self.my_canvas, because I tried to change the fill in the function change_red with itemconfigure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to realize that the `width` property in `create_oval` functions is actually the **`width of the border around the outside of the ellipse. Default is 1 pixel.`** So, even though the color has changed, you are not able to see it visually. For that, you need to change the thickness of your ovals/ellipses or set `width=0` i.e. no border. Here is an example :

```
#I didn't have ImageTk so I have changed it accordingly
import tkinter as tk

class Window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.color = "black"
        self.t = 2
        menubar = tk.Menu(self)
        self.config(menu=menubar)
        operation_menu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        config_menu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Change Color", menu=operation_menu)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=config_menu)
        config_menu.add_command(label="Exit", command=lambda: exit())
        operation_menu.add_command(label="Red", command=lambda: self.change_red())
        self.im = tk.PhotoImage(file="ex.png")
        self.geometry("500x500")
        self.title("Image Editor")
        self.resizable(False, False)
        self.im_cv = tk.Canvas(self, width=300, height=200)
        self.im_cv.pack(expand="yes", fill="both")
        self.im_cv.create_image(50, 10, image=self.im, anchor="nw")
        self.im_cv.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.paint)

    def change_red(self):
        self.color = "red"

    def paint(self, event):
        # print(self.color)
        x1, y1 = (event.x - self.t), (event.y - self.t)
        x2, y2 = (event.x + self.t), (event.y + self.t)
        self.my_canvas = self.im_cv.create_oval(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill=self.color, width=0)

window = Window()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you  Miraj, that solved my problem! Thats means that the width of the outside border was too large I guess.

Comment: @bitbyte Yes, you are right. Using `self.t` you can control the thickness of your drawing. Using the width attribute, you control the border thickness.